# Nested Folders in MVC3 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm a web developer new to using the MVC3 framework. We're building a site that implements a  lot of sub folders for different segments of our audience. This routing concept is throwing a wrench in our structure for SEO.

In my global.asax file under the routing section we have:

```
routes.MapRoute("test", "test/{testFirst}/{testSecond}",
    new { controller = "test", action = "RouteTest", testSecond = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and in my controller we have:

```
public ActionResult RouteTest(string testFirst, string testSecond)
{
    return View(testFirst, testSecond);
}
```

When I run the site and try to go to /test/test/index it won't pull up the view. It's stuck looking for test.cshtml which doesn't exist because it's a folder not a file.

Any ideas on to how make nested folders work?

**EDIT:** 
Here's a branch of the structure we want and maybe it will help with what I'm trying to accomplish.

This is kind of hard to show but it should get the idea across. We have 5 different audiences that come to the site. I broke down 1 audience and what the flow of that audience is.

Not all segments will have products some are just content other segments have that 3rd level and have products to view

audience

- segment
- segment

  - products
- segment

  - products
- segment

This is the basic structure that we want the URLs to take

domain.com/audience/segment/products/(productsname)

Suggestions on how to make this possible

Comment: Sorry. It's not apparent why you wouldn't simply use MVC3 Areas which is part of the framework and works with routing out-of-the-box.

Comment: MVC Areas are overkill for what we're doing. I see areas being more useful for when you have a blog hosted parallel with other sites.

Comment: Overkill, really? How much *work* do you think it requires to employ Areas? Areas is a first-class citizen of MVC3 and works out-of-the-box, accomplishes exactly the solution for what you are asking.

Area = audience, controller = segment, product = view.

Comment: I see that now. If you read the bottom comments. Coming from a non-MVC framework background, Areas were a new concept and seemed like to much for something that was so simple when working with normal folder structures.

Comment: Yeah, Areas do seem almost like a routing hack in the framework -- an afterthought to to support a routing level that extends a node above your controller/method path -- but it is easy enough to implement. We used a hack similar to the answer before we discovered areas, but found that managing the routes and route-specialized controller methods becomes a bigger management headache. I sorely want to refactor that to Area.
Good luck implementing your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload for the `View()` method.  Here's what you're using when you call `View(testFirst, testSecond)`:

```
protected internal ViewResult View(
    string viewName,
    string masterName
)
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470743.aspx).

By putting "test" for the `viewName`, you're telling the Controller to render a View called `Test` (test.cshtml).  Which you don't have.

It sounds to me like you are trying to correlate WebForms with MVC.  It is not the same, and you are seeing a prime example with routing.  ASP.NET MVC doesn't work off of the NTFS structure (folders and files).  It relies on routing through route definitions.

If you are looking to render the View "RouteTest", then do something like this:

```
public ActionResult RouteTest(string testFirst, string testSecond)
{
    ViewBag.testFirst = testFirst;
    ViewBag.testSecond = testSecond;

    return View();
}
```

This will render the "RouteTest" view and in your dynamic object `ViewBag` you will have access to two properties: `testFirst` and `testSecond`.  In your view you can pull those values. (Although I highly recommend strongly-typed Views using a ViewModel)

### Example Solution

**ViewModel**

```
public class TestData
{
    public string testFirst { get ; set ; }
    public string testSecond { get ; set ; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult RouteTest(string testFirst, string testSecond)
{
    TestData td = new TestData();
    td.testFirst = testFirst;
    td.testSecond = testSecond;

    return View(td);
}
```

**Strongly-Typed View**

```
@model TestData

@Html.Label(Model.testFirst)
@Html.Label(Model.testSecond)
```

Comment: Your method sounds like it may work. And I'm actually coming from a PHP background instead of the web form route but the file structure is the same. 

But the problem we're having with routing in MVC is our site audience fits into 5 segments and each segment has between 2-7 sub segments that they fit into from there. And the logical way for us to build this is sub folders. But our team is new to MVC and the concepts so if you have a better suggestion on how to structure this I'm all ears. :)

Comment: @user1198139 Let me know if you're having trouble with getting it working and I can post a full working solution.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand where you were going with that. ha. If you could post that solution with an example of what you're describing that would be great!

Comment: @ddilsaver Check out my edit.  Very simplified, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I actually found a different solution just before you posted this if i pass an absolute path into the View(); it works. Example:
return View(@"~Views\test\test\index.cshtml);

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I think we're going to use Areas instead of this approach I sat down and really dug into them and I think they may be the best way to accomplish our goal